# SQL: How can I select rows from a table that aren't in another one using group by?

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join, where-clause

Suppose that I have a table A with a column id (PK) and a table B with a foreign key to_id that refers to id.

I want to select all rows from A that aren't refered from B.

I thought about the following approach:

```
select * from A group by id having id not in (select to_id from B);
```

But I'd like to know if there is an approach that doens't use "NOT IN".

Something like:

```
select * from A, B group by id having id = to_id and count(to_id) = 0;
```

This one doesn't work, but I'd like something like this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select all rows from A that aren't refered from B.

This reads like `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.to_id = a.id)
```

There is no need to `group by` whatsoever.

Another typical approach is an anti-`left join`:

```
select a.*
from a
left join b on b.to_id = a.id
where b.to_id is null
```

Comment: I've used the anti-left join for so long, but didn't realise it had a name. Would of been guess able, but still a good to know fact.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. But I'd like to use only "group by" and "having", I'd done this using exists and left join as well.

Comment: Why? `group by` and `having` are not the right tools for this job.

Answer (score 0):

Just a left join and a where condition to pull only those which have a null as the b id.

```
select a.*
from a
left join b on b.to_id = a.id
where b.to_id is null
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. But I'd like to use only "group by" and "having", I'd done this using left join as well.